# C# Base64Url conversion of byte array to pre-allocated char array

Tags: c#, arrays, base64url

Is there a way to perform Base64Url conversion of byte array to a pre-allocated char array like [ToBase64CharArray](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.convert.tobase64chararray?view=net-5.0#System_Convert_ToBase64CharArray_System_Byte___System_Int32_System_Int32_System_Char___System_Int32_System_Base64FormattingOptions_) does?

I need to reuse the char buffer instead of getting new string every time, so Base64UrlEncoder is not suitable.

Comment: so basically `ToBase64CharArray` is ok, but you need Base64Url encoding instead of Base64 encoding. Is that correct?

Comment: @jps Yes exactly.
I could use ToBase64CharArray and replace the / + characters manually, but maybe there is an existing method?

Comment: The Azure SDK has [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.identitymodel.tokens.base64urlencoder?view=azure-dotnet)

Comment: ASP.Net has [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.webutilities.webencoders.base64urlencode?view=aspnetcore-5.0)

Comment: @MarkBenningfield Looks like a solution. I will check it. Thank you

Comment: @MarkBenningfield WebEncoders.Base64UrlEncode is suitable, but unfortunately there is no corresponding method to _decode_ from pre-allocated char array to pre-allocated byte array. Please post me if you know such method, thanks